# Raise event in another class in order to execute a function in FormMain, and more parameters are passed

Tags: c#, events

I have problems with the C# syntax when it comes to events.

I have the following code in **FormMain**:
1.) `private TextfileParser TfP = new TextfileParser();`
2.) (in **FormMain_Load**) `TfP.MR += new TextfileParser.MessageBox_required();`
3.) the procedure to be executed.

```
private void MessageBox_required(object sender, EventArgs e, string s)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s,
                            "Database – Load Data",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

**TextfileParser.cs** contains the following code:

```
public delegate void MessageBox_required(object sender, EventArgs e, string Text);
public event MessageBox_required MR;
```

The error reads:

> Compiler Error CS1729: "TextfileParser.MessageBox_required" does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

[image: where the error is]

If I put in arguments, that's also wrong.

I can't cope with the examples on various websites and forums, especially because people create extra classes and procedures. I can't imagine that this has to be done in such a “complicated” way.
Also, I have to pass another parameter (string Text).

Comment: There are no "procedures" in C#.

Comment: @Fildor oh, how do you call them?

Comment: Depends on what you are talking about. `private void MessageBox_required( ...` is a method which serves as an event handler. Some would call it maybe a "void - function". But C# itself doesn't (really in the Turbo-Pascal-Sense) make a distinction between "Procedures" and "Functions". Procedures are really just Functions, that do not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your handler method has the same name as the delegate. For clarity, let's rename your handler method like the following:

```cs
private void OnMessageBoxRequired(object sender, EventArgs e, string s)
{
    MessageBox.Show(s,
        "Database – Load Data",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

The correct syntax to subscribe to your event would then be the following:

```cs
TfP.MR += OnMessageBoxRequired;
```

To raise the event, your `TextfileParser` class needs to do the following:

```cs
MR?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty, "some string");
```

Comment: Ah, I see, these must be different names. Thanks very much!